# OpenGL with PyFace

Tags: python, opengl, enthought, pyface

How I can write an OpenGl application using Enthought Framework? I created a TasksApplication and I am stuck on [this tutorial](http://docs.enthought.com/envisage/tasks_user_manual/layout.html#lifecycle-of-a-task), I don't know what I can use instead `PythonEditor` there. I need to create something where I will be able to render.

**UPDATE:**

I changed the code to

```
def create(self, parent):
    widget = GLWidget(parent)
    self.control = widget
```

Where `GlWidget` is implemented like in [this example](http://qt.gitorious.org/pyside/pyside-examples/blobs/master/examples/opengl/hellogl.py).
And I have a runtime crash. But I am able to run the GL script from the example above.

**UPDATE2:**

[Log file](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5xCwCSQrt7XU3JNajJTVXNWYWs/edit?usp=sharing)

**UPDATE4:**
Code was updated according to @Robert Kern suggestions. Now it works.

[Min Example](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5xCwCSQrt7XWXRFMzRWYjZaOEU&usp=sharing)

[MinExample 7z](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5xCwCSQrt7XWXRFMzRWYjZaOEU&usp=sharing)

Comment: I'm afraid that you will have to provide more information about the crash, like copy-pasting the exact traceback.

Comment: ok. I uploaded the log.

Comment: I'm not seeing an error that is related to a crash, just some tracebacks from trying to load optional PyOpenGL components. Are there no other messages? Why do you think this is a crash? Does a window show up, then immediately disappear? Or does nothing happen? Can you post a complete minimal example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Two things: `Plugin.py` still has `from Task import Visualization` where you should have `from Visualization import Visualization`. And in your `PythonEditorPane` (which it is time to rename) your `create()` method does not assign the `GLWidget` that you instantiated to `self.control`. Fix those two things, and your example works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `control` trait of a `TaskPane` is just the Qt widget object that you are using. In the example that you link, we happen to be getting it from another PyFace widget that wraps a Qt widget in a similar fashion, so we just grab the `control` attribute from it. You should just directly use a [`QGLWidget`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qglwidget.html) as the `control` of your pane. Please consult the Qt documentation for how to use it. You can use [PyOpenGL](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/) in the `paintGL()`, etc. methods to do the actual rendering.